# How to add entry in the registry without knowing the username?

Tags: windows, registrykey

In Windows I need to create a .reg that modifies the value of a string in the registry. Example:

BEFORE
(Value information)

```
C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\myprogram\assets\asset1.png
```

AFTER
(Value information)

```
C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\myprogram\assets\asset2.png
```

I manage to modify it this way because I know the username, my problem is that I want to make it universal, how could I get to that path without having to know the username? (something like when you put %appdata% in the windows window to go C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming Folder)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\myprogram]
"image"="C:\\Users\\dave\\AppData\\Local\\myprogram\\assets\\asset2.png"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: .reg files are not a programming language. They do not support variables.

Answer (score 0):

use "image" as Reg_Expand_Sz regkey (expandable environment string variable) and use "%localappdata%\myprogram\myicon" as value.

Beware though: I stumbled over this old post when looking for an explanation why I am getting incorrect values using oWMI.GetExpandedStringValue. %appdata%, %localappdata%, %username% all are returning incorrect values!

For instance C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming for %appdata%, which should be  C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming and which is correctly resolved in a cmd window echo %appdata%

But in your program your call to the reg_expand_sz registry key may be resolved properly.  Check it out.